# one liner for conditionally replacing dictionary values

Tags: python, refactoring, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there a better way to express this using list comprehension? Or any other way of expressing this in one line?

I want to replace each value in the original dictionary with a corresponding value in the col dictionary, or leave it unchanged if its not in the col dictionary.

```
col = {'1':3.5, '6':4.7}
original = {'1':3, '2':1, '3':5, '4':2, '5':3, '6':4}
for entry in col.iteritems():
    original[entry[0]] = entry[1]
```

Comment: This code snippet doesn't run as-is.  Please provide a code snippet that we can paste into a file and run without modification, so we can easily see what you're doing.

Comment: @Glenn: I didn't have any problem with it. No syntax errors and it did what I think the OP wanted: it updated original values. Why do you think it should have failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) is what you want.

> update([other])
>
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys.
>   Return None.

**Code:**

```
original.update(col[user])
```

**A simple test:**

```
user = "user"

matrix = {
    "user" : {
        "a" : "b",
        "c" : "d",
        "e" : "f",
    },
}

col = {
    "user" : {
        "a" : "b_2",
        "c" : "d_2",
    },
}

original.update(col[user])

print(original)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 'b_2', 'c': 'd_2', 'e': 'f'}
```

Comment: The question says "I want to replace each value in the original dictionary with a corresponding value in the col dictionary, or leave it unchanged if its not in the col dictionary."  Won't this violate the second half of that statement?

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  I think I read the question incorrectly... `col` is the dictionary used to update, not the one being updated.

Comment: @Steve, no. According to the manual, it only overrides existing keys. So any key/value pair in `original` is left untouched if there is no correspondent key in `col[user]`. In my example this was `"e" : "f"`.